# What type of token is this?

Tags: session-management, jwt, web, ctf, access-token

I started noticing this kind of token in a lot of CTF tasks from different authors:

`eyJlbWFpbCI6ImVtYWlsQG1haWxib3guZG9tYWluIiwiaWQiOjN9.ZLNCAQ.MxwKVKj_dramWyfT5XxT6g9U3xk`

The structure is as follows:

1. Payload (usually a json string). In my case it is `{"email":"email@mailbox.domain","id":3}`
2. "Created at" timestamp
3. Some hash

At first I thought it was some kind of self-written implementation of a stateless token (similar to JWT), but since I started noticing it everywhere in different CTFs, I assume it could be a well-known token type. If so, what is it?

Comment: What do you mean "token"? Where are you finding this? Is this in a cookie? It looks like a CTF player ID token.

Comment: The 3 parts separated by a dot and using a signature is consistent with JWT